# how to give auto update functionality in my android apps

Tags: android

I have made an application in which i am using more resources images ,video's ,text files which is in my assets folder of application & i am accessing these resources at run time

through sqlight database.The application is offline application.
now suppose my application is using by many users all over world.

Now the things I wants is that : I wants to maintain my own cloud server Or my server ,so that when i put new resources on server (I mean new images , video's etc.) then these

resources should be automatically update on user's device's who is using the application(when ever user's are connecting through internet).

I don't wants to create new version of my application because i am updating resources.

I am new in android development please suggest.How to make , manage & maintain the server side functionality which will fulfill my need.
  if the things r not clear please let me know.

Regards
Anupam mishra

Comment: is your new resource are in assets? if yes use the Google cloud messaging topic like once device receives the msg from google cloude server then onwards use new resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you say that your files are in the assets folder, which means that they are bundled with the apk and are read only. Therefore, it is not possible to write data to this part of your app, and hence you cannot update it.

Here's what I would recommend:

1. Don't bundle anything with your app. Instead, download the images etc. on the first run of the app, preferably to the external storage if they take up more than a bit of space. Downloading to the internal storage it possible, but most devices have very limited internal storage, and your app is a candidate for immediate uninstall if it hogs this space.
2. Setup a webservice on your server in whatever language you like that can report the latest update date of the files and provide them for download if required.
3. Whenever your app is run, check the last modified date of the downloaded files vs. the last update date provided by your webservice. If the file has been updated since it was downloaded, download it again and overwrite the old one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: 1)if i am getting u:U r suggesting me to put my Resources files & database in the external folder like sdcard of device. then suggest me if i will put resources & database in external folder then user can easily get resources & he will able to update it , then there is no security .2)the concept of webservices I don't know I am right OR wrong please suggest me : for this I need to maintain same resources Folder & database on my server & when any update is held we need to download whole Resources & database from server to device & override the whole resources Or anyother way to do it.

Comment: You can just maintain individual files on both ends, and only update the files which have been updated. You don't need a resources folder as you aren't writing to one on your Android device. You're writing to either the internal or external storage.